# How to cache listview builder in flutter/dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, caching

I have a Listview builder and each item contains text and a picture.
i want these Items stay untill the user remove them, but when i do **hot reload** the items will be removed. how can i cache them? is there any package?

Comment: 1- What do you mean by getting removed? 
2- do you want to cache the images or the whole data?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlhayek i mean cache whole data.

Comment: store them into local database or server.

Answer (score 3):

cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
customCacheManager
set the cache for as long as you want

```
static final customCacheManager = CacheManager(Config('customCacheKey',
      stalePeriod: Duration(days: 15), maxNrOfCacheObjects: 100));


 CachedNetworkImage(
                cacheManager: customCacheManager,
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                imageUrl: urlImage,
                placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF02204c),
                ),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Center(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/imageError.png',
                    height: 60,
                    width: 60,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```